# Google Sheet Script to convert values to Lowercase

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, equality-operator

New to scripting, trying to use the OnEdit() to force lowercase on values in column E

started with a few iteration of the following with no succes...

```
    function onEdit(e) {
      var range = e.range;
      var value = range.getValue();
      if (range.getColumn() = 5 ) {
            e.range.setValue(e.value.toLowerCase());
          } else {
            return;
          }
      }
```

Any easy tweak you can think of to force lowercase on edits in cloumn E?

Thank you,
JF

Comment: Just minor error. It should be `if (range.getColumn() == 5 )`

Answer (score 2):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.columnStart == 5) {
    e.range.setValue(e.value.toLowerCase());
  }
}
```

Generally scripts limit there activity to a specific set of pages and rows.  I suppose you are aware that this trigger will be running for all of your tab/sheets.